# Jersey: get URL of a method

Tags: java, jersey, uri, builder

I want to get URI for specific method without 'hardcoding' it.

I tried `UriBuilder.fromMethod` but it only generates URI that is specified in the `@Path` annotation for that method, it doesn't take into account the `@Path` of the resource class it's in.

For example, here's the class

```
@Path("/v0/app")
public class AppController {

    @Path("/{app-id}")
    public String getApp(@PathParam("app-id") int appid) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

I want to get the URL for the `getApp` method, this `/v0/app/100` for example.

UPDATE:

I want to get the URL from method other than `getApp`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works if you use `UriBuilder.fromResource`, then add the method path with `path(Class resource, String method)`

```
URI uri = UriBuilder
        .fromResource(AppController.class)
        .path(AppController.class, "getApp")
        .resolveTemplate("app-id", 1)
        .build();
```

Not sure why it doesn't work with `fromMethod`.

Here's a test case

```
public class UriBuilderTest {

    @Path("/v0/app")
    public static class AppController {

        @Path("/{app-id}")
        public String getApp(@PathParam("app-id") int appid) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testit() {
       URI uri = UriBuilder
               .fromResource(AppController.class)
               .path(AppController.class, "getApp")
               .resolveTemplate("app-id", 1)
               .build();

        assertEquals("/v0/app/1", uri.toASCIIString());
    }
}
```